# Fast checking Matrix multiplication in mod 10

Tags: matrices, number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I recently faced this problem in a programming contest: Given 3 square matrices N x N of size N up to 1000. All elements in 3 matrices are from 0 to 9. Check if matrix A x B equals to C, mod 10. In other words, return the result of expression (A x B) mod 10 == C.

For example:

A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 5 & 8 \\ 
 1 & 4 & 9 \\ 
 2 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}

B = \begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 6 \\ 
 3 & 7 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

C = \begin{bmatrix}
 9 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
 8 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}

return: TRUE

if
C = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 6 & 0 \\ 
 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 
 8 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}

return: FALSE, since the element C(1, 1) must be 9.

Time limit is 1s, pretty strict. Please gives me some idea how to solve the problem efficiency (is it possible with O(N * N) ?).

Comment: It seems there might be some confusion between base 10 and mod 10. Please double check what you wrote. Maybe give an example.

Comment: You may get some better help at the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, are the values in $A$ and $B$ already single digit? Or can they be any integer?

Comment: mod 10 is very clearly what is meant

Comment: Updated example, please take a look :)

Comment: Sounds like a generalized type of parity check. Maybe that gives you some good intuition to start with. Can you also please provide more information on the source (i.e. what programming contest this comes from, ideally with a link)?